# how to parse HTML tags from json string into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting following json from PHP

```
[{"autoid":"2","package_id":"a78o5jax32","chapter_title":"General Aspects of Surgery","question_text":"Capsule Endoscopy-False statement is","explanation":"<p>Capsuleê Endoscopy is not suitable for patients with strictures.<\/p>","reference":"Bailey and Love 26th Edition P\/205","options":"Sedation Not RequiredxxxxxxPainless ProcedurexxxxxxVisualize Entire small BowelxxxxxxSuitable For Patients With Stricture Bowel","answer":"3"},{"autoid":"3","package_id":"a78o5jax33","chapter_title":"General Aspects of Surgery","question_text":"Physiological changes in laparoscopy include all excep","explanation":"&#8226; Laparoscopyæ causes increased PCWP, Intra cranial Pressure and decreased Functional Residual capacity after expiration is decreased after laparoscopy gas insuffulation.<br \/>&#8226; There will be Hypercarbia and acidosis (pH decrease)<br \/>","reference":"Ref: Schwartz Page 417\/ 10th Edition","options":"Increases PCWPxxxxxxIncreased ICPxxxxxxDecreased FRCxxxxxxIncreased pH","answer":"4"}]
```

I want to show explanation field into HTML DOM. How can I do that. I am trying following code

```
success:function(data){
            var finalData = JSON.parse(data);
            setTimeout(function(){
              var explainText = finalData[0].explanation;
              console.log($.parseHTML(explainText));
              $("#explanationTest").html(explainText)
            },100)
              console.log(finalData);
          }
```

but it show `<p>Capsuleê Endoscopy is not suitable for patients with strictures.</p>` in the HTML document.

Please help

Comment: What element type is explanationTest

Comment: <p id="explanationTest"></p>

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the end tag of paragraph element is escaped in your JSON data: `<\/p>`. Try modifying it to return end tags like `</p>`.

**From:**

```
"explanation": "<p>Capsuleê Endoscopy is not suitable for patients with strictures.<\/p>"
```

**To:**

```
"explanation": "<p>Capsuleê Endoscopy is not suitable for patients with strictures.</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this is difference with yours
but it seems to work properly

https://jsfiddle.net/p71movh8/17/

```
 var finalData = eval(data);
 var explainText = finalData[0].explanation;
 $("#explanationTest").html(explainText);
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can always use pure Javascript that has been long forgotten:

```
$("#explanationTest")[0].innerHTML(explainText)

// OR

document.getElementById('explanationTest').innerHTML(explainText)
```